# SSRS Report Viewer Print Button Not Working

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2016

I'm using SSRS 2016 and am currently generating several reports using the

```
http://[servername]/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/[Report Path]&rc:Parameters=false
```

interface.  The report renders correctly with all parameters supplied by the forwarding page.  However, in the rendered report viewer, the Print Button is entirely non-functional.  I've tried in Chrome, IE, & Edge, and none of them are able to even open a printer prompt, the print button just registers and click and, nothing.

I've ensured Client Printing is enabled in the SSRS settings.  I'm trying to avoid forcing the operator to export to PDF (which does work on the standard toolbar) and using Adobe's print function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past.  I fixed it by opening my browser with "Run as Administrator".   This may not be the solution for *your* problem... but it may help someone who stumbles on this question, so I decided to post as a potential answer.